# Why my navbar is not updating? Navbar is not checking info

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication

HTML:
I already tried using @if but it doesnt change anything

```
      <a routerLink="/cadastro" *ngIf="isLoggedIn">LOGOUT</a>
        
      <a routerLink="/cadastro" *ngIf="!isLoggedIn">LOGIN</a>
```

TYPESCRIPT:
This basicly sets is LoggedIn to true if there is user information on auth Service
But the problem is that the navbar is not getting updated, feels like it needed a refresh or something like this.

```
      export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
      authService: AuthService = inject(AuthService);
      isLoggedIn: boolean = false;


  

      ngOnInit() {
      
      this.authService.user.subscribe((user: User) => {
      
      this.isLoggedIn = user ? true : false;
      
       
      

      console.log(this.isLoggedIn, user)
       });
       }
       }
```

I am no idea how to solve, please help me! Ive already tried changing @if/@else, end using if(user){isloggedin = true} but nothing works!

Comment: This is an change detection issue, as the user seems to be async. Instead of setting local variable you should use the observable in templates using the async pipe or use signals: ``readonly isLoggedIn = toSignal(this.authService.user.pipe(map(user => !!user));``

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 3 things,

1. Check if the guard is successfully updating the values, you can do that by simply logging it
2. Check if that value can be accessed from inside of the component
3. If it doesn't then try re-running the angular change detection

I have added some code below with some proposed changes. Additionally, I have made the isLoggedIn a behaviour subject because there is a current “state” of the isLoggedIn status that you can make available through a subscription. You can also make it a [simple subject](https://levioconsulting.com/insights/intro-to-rxjs-in-angular-observables-subjects-and-behaviorsubjects/) based on your needs

Demo

[image]

Html:

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="logInOuthandler()">
    <span *ngIf="!userLoggedIn.getValue()">Login</span>
    <span *ngIf="userLoggedIn.getValue()">Logout</span>
<button>
```

Header component:

```
export class HeaderComponent {

  userLoggedIn : BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);


  logInOuthandler(){
    let currentStatus = this.userLoggedIn.getValue();
    this.userLoggedIn.next(!currentStatus)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this optimized code. use behavior subject in the auth service which will be changed in the auth service if the user is logged in or not.
and use that with built-in async pipe directly in the HTML file.